# Derivation of Davidson's Slingshot Argument in Standard FOL

Tags: metaphysics, truth, donald-davidson

Davidson's slingshot argument employs two principles:
Equivalence: If two sentences are logically equivalent, then they correspond to the same fact.
Co-reference: Substituting co-referring terms preserves correspondence.

Using these two principles the following argument could be run. Suppose Fa and Gb are true in some interpretation. Then:

(1) Fa

(2) (ιx x=m)=ιx(x=m∧Fa) (by equivalence)

(3) (ιx x=m)=ιx(x=m∧Gb) (by co-reference)

(4) Gb                  (by equivalence)

It thus follows that Fa and Gb corresponds to the same fact...

My question is how to translate "(ιx x=m)=ιx(x=m∧Fa)" into standard first order logic. And how does one show that this identity statement is logically equivalent to Fa? I've tried and it doesn't seem to work. I know that "ιx x=m" is supposed to mean the x such that x is m.

Comment: If you translate ιx x=m to ∃x(x=m ∧ ∀y(x=m → x= m)) (which is probably the most intuitive translation), ∃x(x=m ∧ ∀y(x=m → x= m))= ∃x(x=m ∧ ∀y(x=m → x= m) ∧Fa) simply wouldn't make sense because neither side of the equality are actually singular terms so the sentence isn't well-formed.

Comment: The issue is that "iota" when apied to a formula produces a term, i.e. a name. Thus, you cannot replace it with a formula.

Comment: But the argument is based simpmy on the fact that, if Fa, then x=m and (x=m and Fa) are equivalent. Thus, applying "iota" to both, the result will be the same object.

Comment: this principle of equivalence seems suspicious: equiprovability depends both on underlying theory and logic, and if 'equivalent' sentences suddenly stop being so when one drops/weakens some axiom, were they really speaking of the same stuff to begin with?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I see, that makes sense. so then the resulting sentence would be m= m∧Fa ?

Comment: @ac15 Yes you’re absolutely right. This is under the backdrop of classical logic.

Comment: Davidson took the ℩ symbol from *Principia*, where they give its intended translation, see [What is the ℩ symbol in formal logic?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/51566/9148)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(ιx.P[x])=(ιx.Q[x])

can be roughly translated into FOL with equality as

(∃!x.P[x])∧(∃!x.Q[x])∧(∀x,y.P[x]∧Q[y]→x=y)

where ∃!x means "there exists a unique x" and P[x] represents a formula with a variable slot that is replaced with the variable in the brackets.

I say "roughly" because technically ιx.P[x] doesn't imply that there is a unique x such that P[x], rather the existence of such a unique x is a prerequisite for the expression to be meaningful.

Comment: If (ιx.P[x])=(ιx.Q[x]) is meaningful, it would mean that the x must be both P and Q, right? But the translation doesn’t imply that, the P and Q could be distinct

Comment: @ayylien i think ur right.. perhaps the correct translation is this: ∃x(Px∧ ∀y(Py→ x=y))∧ ∃x(Qx∧ ∀y(Qy→ x=y))∧ ∀x(Qx<->Px)

Comment: @ayylien, no, x is a different variable on each side of the equation. You could replace the second one with y and it would mean the same thing.

Comment: @DavidGudeman I meant that it means: there is exactly one P and exactly one Q, and they are the same thing. But the translation says there is exactly one P and exactly one Q, and if there is anything that is both P and Q, there is one. But there might not be any

Comment: @ayylien, no the translation says that there is one P and one Q, and that if you have a P and a Q  (which you do by the first two clauses) then they are the same. For "if there is anything both P and Q" one would write P[x]∧Q[x].